# Get current authentication provider in .NET Core

Tags: authentication, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.2 MVC web-application, and it supports 2 types of authentication:

1. Login/password and local database;
2. Azure AD.

I need a way to know how the current user is authenticated. So far I could only think of checking the `Issuer` value of the very first claim:

```cs
string authType = HttpContext.User.Claims.ElementAt(0).Issuer;
```

Here're the values I get depending on the authentication type:

1. `LOCAL AUTHORITY`
2. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT-ID-HERE/v2.0`

So it kinda works, but relying on the first element of the list (`Claims.ElementAt(0)`) doesn't look good to me.

Is there some other way, something like `HttpContext.User.AuthenticationProvider.Name`?

Comment: Have you tried `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType`?

Comment: Hm, this one gave me `Cookies` for "local" authentication and `AuthenticationTypes.Federation` for Azure AD, so I can use that too. But can I get anything more meaningful out of `AuthenticationTypes.Federation`, for example if I'll have more authentication providers, how to distinguish Azure AD from others? Either way, if there won't be any other answers, I'll accept yours.

Comment: For multiple auth schemes, you can use JWT and add a claim of `AuthType`. Then you can know which authentication is being used.